# Detecting Orientation Change with Event Listener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, starling-framework

I'am work on ActionScript mobile project , i'am using starling with AS3 , i try to add event listener to detect ORIENTATION_CHANGE event in starling class but it will not detect the change , if i add event listener in AS3 class (Main class) will detect and will call the starling class again .

main class of AS3 :

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;

import starling.core.Starling;

public class mainClass extends Sprite
{
    private var myStarling:Starling;
    public function mainClass()
    {
        super();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,onResize);
        stage.addEventListener(flash.events.StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE,shangedOr);
    }
    private function shangedOr(e:StageOrientationEvent):void
    {
        // code 
    }
    private function onResize(e:Event):void
    {
        myStarling = new Starling(Main,stage);
        myStarling.start();
    }
}
```

}

starling class : i add new AS class and make it starling class

```
package
 {
import feathers.controls.ScrollContainer;
import feathers.layout.VerticalLayout;
import feathers.themes.AeonDesktopTheme;
import flash.events.Event;
import feathers.controls.Label;
import feathers.controls.TextInput;
import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
import org.osmf.layout.VerticalAlign;

import starling.display.DisplayObject;
import starling.display.Sprite;
import starling.display.Stage;
import starling.events.Event;

public class starlingClass extends starling.display.Sprite
{
    private var newLayout:VerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    private var container:ScrollContainer = new ScrollContainer();
    public function starlingClass()
    {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(starling.events.Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addToStage);
        this.addEventListener(flash.events.StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING,orientationChange);

    }
    private function addToStage(e:starling.events.Event):void
    {
        this.theme = new AeonDesktopTheme( this.stage );
        drawComponent();
    }
    private function orientationChange(evt:StageOrientationEvent):void
    {
        // orientation will not responce to change orientation.
    }
    private function drawComponent():void
    {
        var button:feathers.controls.Button = new feathers.controls.Button();
        button.label = "Click Me";
        var newLabel:Label = new Label();
        newLabel.text = "hello world";
        var txt:TextInput = new TextInput();
        var layout:VerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        var container:ScrollContainer = new ScrollContainer();
        container.layout = layout;
        container.addChild(button);
        container.addChild(newLabel);
        container.addChild(txt);
        this.addChild( container );
        layout.paddingTop = 10;
        layout.paddingRight = 15;
        layout.paddingBottom = 10;
        layout.paddingLeft = 15;
        layout.gap = 5;
    }
}
}
```

the problem : `mainClass.as` will detect the orientation change and will call `starlingClass.as` and no component shown . `starlingClass.as` will never detect the orientation change maybe because i detect an flash event  inside starling class ..
any help

Comment: Try official info about it: http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/auto-rotation Basicly you need to detect resizes and orientation changes outside starling and pass the information into it. That's how Starling works :P

Comment: i changed as requested in link , orientation will disable . And resize will not detected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer is :
 there is a mistake in my code , the problem in this function :

```
private function onResize(e:Event):void
{
    myStarling = new Starling(Main,stage);
    myStarling.start();
}
```

because every change orientation will call `onResize` method , to call it again of starling.
solution is very simple :

```
private function onResize(e:flash.events.Event):void
    {
        if (myStarling == null)
        {
            myStarling = new Starling(Main,stage);
            myStarling.start(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add event listener over nativeStage like below:

this.nativeStage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, onOrientationChanging);

Because "stage" you have used is Starling stage.

Comment: if you check the question again you will see that flash Event will not work on starling class .. `this.nativeStage` not exist in starling class .. i wondered if i can pass a parameter from flash class to starling class , do you have any idea ?